# nuxt unable to find runtime.js

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

Just done a fresh install if nuxt, everything seems to be working however the javascript console is throwing an error about not being able to load runtime.js

```
GET https://somedomain.com/_nuxt/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I have googled this and also tried to search the issue on the github repo but can find no other references to this issue.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot the cause of this ?